# Want to use a Managed Identity instead of Service principal for existing linked services in Azure Data Factory programtically

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Currently , In ADF linked services using Service Principal i want to convert them to MSI .

Could you please  let me know how to update existing linked services  like  programmatically / REST API/ Script

```
{

  "name" : "ls_stg_storage_dem001",

  "type" : "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices",

  "properties" : {

    "type" : "AzureBlobFS",

    "typeProperties" : {

      "url" : https://testdus001.dfs.core.windows.net,

      "servicePrincipalId" : "7d678787-de8d-890c-ac12-12c103837176",

      "servicePrincipalCredentialType" : "ServicePrincipalKey",

      "tenant" : "5136756a0-2a40-46a5-a970-6f08bf1678af",

      "encryptedCredential" : "Q180YWZlMTA3Yi0xZTAxLTRmOTEtYTMyZC0wNmNlZmE2ZDc3YmQiDQp9ogIktleSIsDQogICJTZWNyZXRDb250ZW50VHlwZSI6ICJQbGFpbnRleHQiLA0KICAiQ3JlZGVudGlhbElkIjogIkRBVEFGQUNUT1JZQDJGQzkwMjlELUZGOE"

    }

  }

}
```

Thank you,
Sunny

I have no idea how to do it that's why i am posting here.

Comment: Can you explain how is the current deployment or other changes planned for your adf? Any reason why you want to update via Programaticaly

Answer (score 0):

You can update the azure blob linked service with managed authentication using portal without following programmatically.

Assign storage blob data contributor role to ADF workspace

[image]

Open existing blob storage linked service and change authentication to managed identity and select blob account test the connection and save it. It will update successfully.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I need to do programmatically with out using portal UI.

Comment: @Sunny Check this Document https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/data-factory/data-factory-service-identity.md

Comment: Thank you. I did using these links.      https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-service-identity